# Wubi Installation program for 14.04 reported a "Permission Denied" error

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, wubi

I downloaded `ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64` and followed instructions to install onto my PC with 4GB RAM and 114 GB free disk space running Wins 7 Professional. After I ran the `wubi.exe` installation program, it reported an permission denied error and I couldn't find the log file in:

```
c:\users\00013851\appdata\local\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log
```

There's no such directory path. I have tried the 32-bit version but faced the same error.

Comment: Try installing without WUBI.

Comment: There is no `wubi.exe` for 14.04.1 (so it would try to download 14.04 anyway). The permission denied could be for other reasons though - so look in that log file you think doesn't exist - it does but part of the path is hidden by windows. Either open the whole thing in notepad as you have written it, or go to the `%TEMP%` directory. Maybe pastebin it. But actually @Akiva is correct. Better not to use Wubi these days.